# Client Certificate Authentication using Owin

Tags: c#, owin, client-certificates

I'm trying to implement client certificate authentication using the OWIN pipeline, and according to Dominick Baier's blog from late 2013 (http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/11/client-certificate-authentication-middleware-for-katana/), you can do that by creating a custom authentication handler:

```
public class ClientCertificateAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        var cert = Context.Get<X509Certificate2>("ssl.ClientCertificate");
        if (cert == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        try
        {
            Options.Validator.Validate(cert);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        var claims = GetClaimsFromCertificate(cert, cert.Issuer, Options.CreateExtendedClaimSet);
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaims(claims);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        return Task.FromResult(ticket);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `GetClaimsFromCertificate` no longer appears either in the base class, or in the `ClaimsIdentity` class.  I'm guessing it's moved, but I've searched in all of the obvious places and drawn a blank.  Does anyone know what has happened to this useful method?

Comment: I'm a bit late but I had the same problem, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimsidentity.getclaimsfromcertificate.aspx) `GetClaimsFromCertificate` is contained in `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims` namespace, you can get it in Microsoft.IdentityModel package from NuGet. I haven't tried it yet, but I hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You  could try using the Thinktecture.IdentityModel Nuget package and use the code below to create the identity:

```
var identity = Identity.CreateFromCertificate(cert, Options.AuthenticationType, Options.CreateExtendedClaimSet);
```

There is a GetClaimsFromCertificate on the X509Util class documented here in Mi at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/X509Util.cs but it is internal :(